# ggplot2 file output issues

Tags: r, ggplot2

Evening.  I'm starting to get my head around ggplot2 and managed to create a bunch of plots today.   **BUT** I've hit two snags.  The first is the way the output looks when creating plots automatically.   ***Can someone please set me straight?***

When I run the plot manually using...

```
ggplot(l.Exploration$Data,aes_string(x="domain",y="WP0", color="domain")) +
    geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=0.3), alpha=0.4) +
    geom_boxplot(size=1,alpha=0.9, outlier.size=1, outlier.shape=21, width=0.75, notch=TRUE) +
    facet_wrap(~Exchange, ncol=2) +
    ggtitle(plotTitle) +
    theme(plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.5), lineheight=.9, face="bold", colour="black")) +
    xlab("Exchange") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
    ylab("Weighted Price ($USD)")
```

I get a neat plot thus...
[image: Manual initiated plot]

BUT when I create the plot as part of a loop and have them auto-save they look awful (AND yes I know the `aes_string(...,Y="WP0")` is the bit that should be making use of `i` but I can't figure that out either).

*The second problem is how to specify the aes_string properly for Y. (I'll move this to another question)*

```
 l_ply(-3:3, function(i){
  print(i)
  path     <- "~/Documents/1. Dev/r/data/plot"
  filename <- paste(path,"/Story_Price",i,".png",sep="")
  yCol  <- paste("l.Exploration$Data$WP",i,sep="")

  if(i < 0)         { plotTitle <- paste("Story Publication Against Price\n[Lead = ",i,"]",sep="") 
  } else if (i==0)  { plotTitle <- paste("Story Publication Against Price",sep="") 
  } else if (i>0)   { plotTitle <- paste("Story Publication Against Price\n[Lag = ",i,"]",sep="") 
  }

  ggplot(l.Exploration$Data,aes_string(x="domain",y="WP0", color="domain")) +
    geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=0.3), alpha=0.4) +
    geom_boxplot(size=1,alpha=0.9, outlier.size=1, outlier.shape=21, width=0.75, notch=TRUE) +
    facet_wrap(~Exchange, ncol=2) +
    ggtitle(plotTitle) +
    theme(plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.5), lineheight=.9, face="bold", colour="black")) +
    xlab("Exchange") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
    ylab("Weighted Price ($USD)") 

    dev.print(png, filename,res=600, height=1600, width=2500, units="px")
})
```

[image: Odd looking ggplot output]

Comment: Use `ggsave`, not `dev.print`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's tackle the size issue, which addresses one of the two distinct questions you're asking.

**Problem:** 
Your parameters for `dev.print` gave you a graph that is approximately 4 x 3. The graphics can't fit in this space, so they're getting cut off.

`ggplot2` has its own save command, `ggsave`, which makes it much easier to control your dimensions.

**Solution:**
Try replacing `dev.print` with this:

```
ggsave(file = "filename.png", dpi = 600, width = 8, height = 6, units = "in")
```

The greater the `dpi`, the larger the graphics will appear. Test this along with other arguments in `ggsave` as part of your `ggplot2` plot and you'll find a fit that saves in a presentable fashion.

Comment: Thanks Dan & Gregor.  I had originally been using ggsave but was getting output that looked like a kid's book.  I had assumed that if using a vector based format (say PDF) that it would scale neatly on output but certainly specifying a larger height and width makes all the difference in terms of layout quality.  Cheers again